# Accord net multi class SVM training + crossvalidating is very slow

Tags: machine-learning, svm, deep-learning, libsvm, accord.net

I'm working with accord.net for a while now, btw a greate api! ,
I'm using multi class svm's with rbf kernel and SMO as a learning algorithm,
My dataset consist of 53 labels of 5k samples each,
Each sample consist of 400 features scaled using z-scores 
I'm trying to run a grid search with crossvalidation to tune the hyperparameters (C and gamma),
But the performence are not very good ,..
When i use a partial dataset which consist of 200 samples for each label , one 2-folds CV run takes about 30 mins,
So a full grid search with 5x5 grid will take about 12.5 hours..
Now, if it was on my full dataset i would be happy with this results but it's on less the 10℅ of it,..
I don't even try to use all of my dataset..,

The complexity range i want to explore is 10^-5 .....10^5 , and the gamma range is 10^-9.....10^3, 
5 values for each of the above,
Is there anything i can i do to accelerate the proccess?

Comment: There is probably not much you can do. Two things come to mind: multi-class should be OneVsAll (or some natural multi-class SVM if supported, but i doubt it) instead of OneVsOne. And you can try to increase the kernel cache-size (this one decides if the complexity is more near samples^2 or samples^3). But keep in mind, that the runtime is also dependent on the parameters. If C is set to small regulization, runtimes will increase a lot. This is likely to happen during parameter-sweeps in CV. **Kernel-SVM training is quite complex!**

Comment: If i read the docs correctly OneVsOne is default, but OneVsRest (aka OneVsAll) can be used. Try this first.

Comment: How can i change the default behaiver to onevsall?

Comment: Read the API. You would need to change the constructor passing an OneVsRest object.